Probabilistic selection of values
I'm working on an optimization problem involving a list-type variable with a large number of values, and to guide the solver, I'm trying to implement a probabilistic selector for the values so that it attempts to allocate values that are likely to have the most impact on the results. My problem involves several teams that must perform a list of constructions sequentially.
My solver is set up as follows:

<localSearch>
        <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
        <forager>
            <acceptedCountLimit>100</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
        <acceptor>
            <valueTabuRatio>0.3</valueTabuRatio>
        </acceptor>
        <ValueSelector variableName="construction">
            <selectionOrder>PROBABILISTIC</selectionOrder>
          <probabilityWeightFactoryClass>(class package)ConstructionWeightFactory</probabilityWeightFactoryClass>
        </ValueSelector>
    </localSearch>

However, this doesn't seem to work, and the probabilityWeightFactoryClass class isn't even executed. I searched for configuration examples, but I couldn't find any that use a probabilistic selector.

Not sure if that is part of the problem, but I think your ValueSelector should be "valueSelector" (note case sensitivity).

I didn't notice that detail, but the code is correct with the lowercase letter
